# randomly select rows(50%) from csv file based on each images names in first column of .csv file

Tags: python

I want to randomly select rows(50%) **from each image**. I don't want to select randomly 50%rows from all total rows.

**I only want randomly select 50% rows based on each image's name in the first column of .csv file. In .csv files have 37 images.**

My codes are as follows that are selected randomly from total rows. I want to select 50% rows based on images.

nlinesfile = 25601

nlinesrandomsample = 1280

lines2skip = np.random.choice(np.arange(1,nlinesfile+1), (nlinesfile-nlinesrandomsample), replace=False)

df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=lines2skip)

data of my .csv file is as follows:

```
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I only want randomly select 50% rows based on each image's name in the first column of .csv file. In .csv files have 37 images. please guide me, sir.

Comment: Does image have duplicates?  Do you want to group same image name and select 50% from that group? Please clarify.

Comment: yes, of course, sir. I want to select 50% from group which consists of the same images name. if we do group the names of the images, we got 37 groups because it has 37 images, and then I want to select randomly 50% rows from each group.

Answer (score 0):

First read the csv, select what ypu want to a list, then use the following code to take a random sample to get a random sample with half the length of the list.

```
from random import sample 

  
# Prints list of random items of given length 

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  

  

print(sample(list1,int(len(list1)/2))
```

Comment: Dear sir, could you do show more details codes for me. it is important to publish paper.

Comment: I have no idea how to help you if you dont know how to use the code

Comment: Dear sir, I face encountered a problem to-do list. because I have 37 images in which have a range of 60 - 200 nuclei per image. I need to select 50% of nuclei from each image. so, how can I list about 200 nuclei from each image and do that process for 37 images simultaneously using a loop? please guide  me, sir.